# What does the command "cat /tmp/dir/:0" do?

Tags: security, bash, x11

When I did the command above, X11 opened. I am perplexed. Did I run it? How can I be sure that I do not run any program when looking at things? I really hate the idea that reading a text file may execute a program. How is it programmable possible to make programs that executes when running a simple cat-command, or similar command?

Comment: So what exactly happened? You were at a text terminal and X started up? Why were you running that command?

Comment: @Zifte: I had read that the thing :0 correspond to a display and X keeps its files in /tmp/. So it was logical to test how things really work. I was waiting for to read some nice code, but I got only a display open.

Comment: Did you type 'cat /tmp/:0' ? I assume the initial $ is your shell prompt?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you run

```
file /tmp/:0
```

you should see that this is not a normal 'text' file but a socket. Aliasing `ls` thus

```
ls -F
```

will help identify such files automatically in your shell.

Answer (score 3):

This sounds like OSX 10.5 behaviour.

launchd listens on a socket '/tmp/launch-xxxxxx/:0'.  The DISPLAY variable is set to tell X applications to write to that socket.  When an X application opens the socket, launchd automatically starts 'X11.app' to provide the application with a display.

cat'ing the socket opens it and triggers X11.app.  I don't think there are any other instances of that behaviour configured by default.

Answer (score 2):

machine:0 is an X display (the first display on 'machine')
I have never seen /tmp/:0 but it might be that your machine is configured so that all unmatched machine names map onto localhost.
You haven't executed anything, the X server will simply try and interpret any commands sent by cat as X instructions. It's like doing cat to an http address

Comment: Can you clarify 'sent by cat' ? I think you mean 'cat X > Y', but there's no redirection in the above

Comment: There would be if he had sent some!

Comment: Your observation is probably right. I rechecked the tmp and I could only find :0 one dir deeper. I changed the question accordingly. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

The `:0` thing is a socket refering to the X server. Programs use this socket to communicate with the X server (for example to draw a window). Reading from this socket somehow caused the server to activate. The X server must have been already running before you did this command.

Comment: I had played with the X-server. So you are probably right that it was running.